# Typescript Error: Base constructor return type 'InstanceType<T>' is not an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a basic class decorator in typescript that does nothing. Here's the relevant code:

```js
const test = () => <T extends new (...rest: any[]) => InstanceType<T>> (Target: T) => {
    class NewTarget extends Target {}

    Object.setPrototypeOf(NewTarget.prototype, Object.getPrototypeOf(Target.prototype));

    return NewTarget;
};
```

The usage would be something like this:

```js
@test()
class Test {}

new Test();
```

I am unable to compile this code, the error being `Base constructor return type 'InstanceType<T>' is not an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members ts(2509)`. I have hit a roadblock.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YAoCUKB8MA8AKjPAB4JgAmEMY8A7ugHTMBOiUAXDAIZgCeAbQC6WZLgCSkKL2DwCfAA7xC2XGgLcWAc3icYBUbgDeAKACQwADbcI1AHL0N23cTLxK1JzthGAvifMAeQAjACt4YChGCF0ABRYQKETFeECAMzQHOi9dRgUEpKgUgBoYEPDIxm94xOSldPVNbzyCuvgMDABuALM2KABXFjAYLJyobt9uk1IFEBZYCng07n7LWARobqA)

Comment: As a workaround, you can change inheritance to `extends (Target as any)`

Comment: @tenbits I don't want a workaround. I want to understand what I am doing wrong and how to properly fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

Whenever we make a new instance of a class, it always returns some kind of object (it can never return anything of a primitive type). So basically, instead of `InstanceType<T>`, I had to write `Record<never, unknown>`. Now the final code looks like this:

```js
const test = () => <T extends new (...rest: any[]) => Record<never, unknown>> (Target: T) => {
    class NewTarget extends Target {}

    Object.setPrototypeOf(NewTarget.prototype, Object.getPrototypeOf(Target.prototype));

    return NewTarget;
};

export default test;
```

This could potentially be a typescript bug because `InstanceType<T>` should be compatible with object type, again due to the above reasoning.

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52139)